# javascript neuralnet back-propagation algorithm failing

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, tree, backpropagation

I'm having trouble building a recursive function to travel correctly along a network.

The problem: an array of objects called cells, have a function:

```
whatIwant(wanted value, bucket array)
```

that calls itself for each connection to the last 'generation' of cells.

With a ( 3 generation by 2 order )+3 'answer'cells) count of cell objects I should get 27 recursive calls? I am getting 107200 items in my return array - instead of 27.

```
IF i don't call Flat() in the code: the return array is in a weird recursive pattern:
(34) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, Array(34), {…}, {…}, Array(34), {…}, {…}, Array(34), Array(34), {…}, {…}, {…}, Array(34), {…}, {…}, Array(34), {…}, {…}, Array(34), Array(34), {…}, {…}, {…}, Array(34), {…}, {…}, Array(34), {…}, {…}, Array(34), Array(34)]
where each array of 34 is yet another array of exactly this array.
```

How I think it should work is as follows:(what I think I wrote)
the brain object calls whatIWant() on each 'answer cell' at the end, it calculates all the adjustments needed, then on each of it's previous layer targets, it call that objects.whatIwant() feeding in as a value- the desiredObject.activation[i] (the value this cell would that activation) and as the array, a reference to an array generated outside this function - that starts empty, continually pushing an updateobjectcontainer that get applied to the braincell after all answerCell.whatIWant() is called by the brain, and those arrays are summed/averaged together.

the path of recursion in my head (with a 3gen:2order){cell.gen3,order0}calls to {cell.gen2,order0},calls to {cell.gen1.order0}calls to {cell.gen0.order0), returns back into {cell.gen1.order0} which calls to cell.gen0.order1} which returns back into {cell.gen1.order0} which returns {cell.gen2.order0} which calls{cell.gen1.order0} which calls{cell.gen0.order0}. and it continues until it reaches back the top lair having traversed the matrix multiple times.

if i do not call flat, it creates an array of objects 
hopefully someone can tell me simply and quickly why I'm an idiot.

```js
some quick helper function defs:

Flat() = returns an array that has been recursively flattened;
Sigmoid() maps all input to between 0-1;
ArrayMultiply() takes two arrays and multiplies against index return a number;
brain.cellArray is the bucket for all the cells;

//
//recusion logic
whatIwant:function(answerValue, returnArray)
            {
         //stuff here that calculates an 
         //objects value(represents the desired 
         //change to the real cell above this 
        //abstraction we combine/average duplicates
       //entries formed in this return array
            if(Array.isArray(cell.lastGenerationTargetKeys) && cell.lastGenerationTargetKeys.length)
                {
                cell.lastGenerationTargetKeys.forEach(x=> returnArray.push(brain.cellArray[x].whatIwant(desiredObjectChange.activations[x], returnArray))); 
                return Flat(returnArray);
            }
            else  
                {
                returnArray.push(desiredObjectChange);      
                return Flat(returnArray);
            }
```

edit/updated for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

So looking at it with fresher eyes, what was happening was: I was traveling through the network correctly, but I wasn't handling the array correctly.

I was pushing the reference of the returnArray into itself, when an item in an array is the array that it's in... bad times.

The updated code is such:

```js
if(Array.isArray(cell.lastGenerationTargetKeys) && cell.lastGenerationTargetKeys.length)
{               
    let nextActivation = desiredObjectChange.activations[Symbol.iterator]();
    cell.lastGenerationTargetKeys.forEach(x => brain.cellArray[x].whatIwant(nextActivation.next().value, returnArray)); 
    return returnArray;
}
else  
{
    return;     
}
```

Comment: Glad you found it.  I wasn't following the question very well, but I didn't even have reasonable questions to ask for clarification.